# Realm filter CLLocation

Tags: ios, swift, realm, cllocation

I have warpper class for CLLoaction

**Wrapper**

```
class Location: Object {
    dynamic var long: Double = 0
    dynamic var lat: Double = 0
}
```

I have to filter stored `Location` for those which are in 1km radius based on my current location. I thought NSPredicate with block would do the job, but realm doesn't support it. So my question is how other way I can achieve it?
Of course I could do something like this:

```
let locations = realm.objects(Location)
var locationsInRadius = [Location]()
for l in locations {
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: l.lat, longitude: l.long)
    if (location.distanceFromLocation(currentLocation) < radius){
        locationsInRadius.append(l)
    }
}
```

But it feels wrong according to whole realm concept of filters.

Answer (score 4):

You can't search for objects by distance, but you can search by using a bounding box.  Simply add `latitude` and `longitude` fields to your object, then:

1. Get current location
2. Create a bounding box around that location
3. Filter your objects by bounding box

In code, that could like this:

```
    // 0. This example uses MapKit to calculate the bounding box
    import MapKit

    // 1. Plenty of answers for this one...
    let currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.7749295, -122.4194155)

    // 2. Create the bounding box with, 1km radius
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentLocation, 1000, 1000)
    let northWestCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
        currentLocation.latitude + (region.span.latitudeDelta),
        currentLocation.longitude - (region.span.longitudeDelta)
    )
    let southEastCorner = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(
        currentLocation.latitude - (region.span.latitudeDelta),
        currentLocation.longitude + (region.span.longitudeDelta)
    )

    // 3. Filter your objects
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "lat BETWEEN {%f, %f} AND lon BETWEEN {%f, %f}",
        northWestCorner.latitude,
        southEastCorner.latitude,
        northWestCorner.longitude,
        southEastCorner.longitude
    )

    let nearbyLocations = realm.objects(MyLocation).filter(predicate)
```

Note that you can still store your `CLLocation` object for other purposes, but you won't need it for the search.

Also note that as this searches a box rather than what you wanted, a circle with a 1km radius, this can return results of greater than 1km. If that's not ok, you would need to reduce the radius or make a fancier predicate.

Comment: Well.. to be honest I already do it what you said, but I was hoping that there is well known NSPredicate (not block based). :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean...  This *is* a search using a well known NSPredicate and there is no block... can you explain?  Also, this is not at all like the example you show... this does not load every object in your realm as the example does, just the ones you need.

Comment: Note in advance that there is a [PR in the making](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/pull/2199/files), which brings this functionality to the binding, but uses the same underlying approach of bounding boxes.

Comment: That's great news!  And I like the use of `between` in that PR instead of gte/lte. Much less prone to error.

Comment: Well done! For next devs, make sure that the first variable in the between is lower than the second... Spent one hour to figure it out ;)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, using a single predicate (`lat BETWEEN {%f, %f} AND lon BETWEEN {%f, %f}`) doesn't work with the current version of Realm. I'm using this nice lib: https://github.com/mhergon/RealmGeoQueries

This is how the predicate is built inside and it works fine: https://github.com/mhergon/RealmGeoQueries/blob/master/GeoQueries.swift:

```
 let topLeftPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K <= %f AND %K >= %f", latitudeKey, box.topLeft.latitude, longitudeKey, box.topLeft.longitude)
 let bottomRightPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K >= %f AND %K <= %f", latitudeKey, box.bottomRight.latitude, longitudeKey, box.bottomRight.longitude)
 let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [topLeftPredicate, bottomRightPredicate])
```

Basically, here is how to use it:

```
let results = try! Realm()
    .findNearby(YourModelClass.self, origin: location.coordinate, radius: 500, sortAscending: nil)
```

You can also change the default "lat" and "lng" keys by passing 2 extra parameters with your own naming (latitudeKey and longitudeKey).

Thanks to https://github.com/mhergon for providing this lib.